# Start time and end time relating to the start of an event and end of an event

Tags: usability, user-research, ux-field, datetimepicker, task-flow

I'm trying to figure out what the best design format will be for an event selection tool.

Issue: The start time is strictly related to the start date of the event (Example, July 30th, 2018 at 3:00pm) you can think of it as a check-in time. The end time is strictly related to the end date (Example, event is 3 days long and ends on the 3rd day at 5:00PM)

I've looked at it a few ways:
[image]
a) Start Date - End Date (Same line)  /  Start Time - End Time

b) Start Date - Start Time / End Date - End Time

I've looked at how other companies are doing it like Facebook & Google and rental car companies etc.

Maybe I just need to do some more research, one can never do enough of that but what are your thoughts on how to relate the start date to the start time and end date to end time such that it's not possible to confuse the start & end time with being the start and end time of each day of the event? I hope this makes sense.

Maybe I'm approaching this all wrong, any input is VERY welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, because our eyes normally read things from left to right (I suppose unless you're native right-to-left language speaker/reader), your top approach seems like the best bet to me.

Your bottom solution seems as if it dissociated time and dates for start and end.

I also would consolidate Start time + date and End time + date. Have a look at the screenshot below.

[image]

Or something along those lines - styling of course is up to you and your team.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup thank you! I think I was coming full circle again back to that design but I like your reasoning.

Comment: glad it has helped:)